# Hack for shortening \diagup?

Tags: symbols, packages, overlap

I have the following problem: I need some `\boxdiag` and `\boxbslash` symbols, but I'm still too much of a TeX n00b, so I have no idea what to do when packages clash. In this case, any package I tried that had a `\boxdiag` symbol in the end clashed with `amsmath` (?), `\vec` being found red-handed. Since I am a very sneaky n00b, I found a way to at least have a neat `\boxbslash` emulator: `\mathrlap{\smallsetminus}\square`. Note that `\smallsetminus` perfectly fits into `\square`. Which `\diagup` doesn't. So, I'm looking for `\foobar` with `\foobar:\smallsetminus=\diagup:\diagdown`. (Even tried `\mathrlap{\angle}\square` :-) Changing the font size of `\diagup` doesn't seem to work either inside `\mathrlap` (its a math environment). Or do you have another idea that doesn't involve mutually crosschecking 20 packages?

Comment: I would rather guess that font packages might have clashed with `amssymb` rather than `amsmath`. Is your question basically "how to get `\boxdiag` in a standard CM setup"?

Comment: a) you're probably right with the first, b) what's a CM? (me n00b, n00b ;-) - you're probably right with that too in any way)

Comment: Sorry: CM stands for Computer Modern, the standard font used by (La)TeX. If you are using some other font packages you should provide a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/82917) with what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fits within the existing size of `\square`. Let the bowling commence!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel,amssymb,stackengine}
\DeclareRobustCommand\boxdiag{\boxslsh{1}}
\DeclareRobustCommand\boxbslash{\boxslsh{-1}}
\newcommand\boxslsh[1]{
\mathchoice{
  \ensurestackMath{\stackengine{0pt}{\square}
  {\stretchrel*[80]{\hstretch{#1}{/}}{\square}}{O}{c}{F}{T}{L}}
}{
  \ensurestackMath{\stackengine{0pt}{\square}
  {\stretchrel*[80]{\hstretch{#1}{/}}{\square}}{O}{c}{F}{T}{L}}
}{
  \ensurestackMath{\stackengine{0pt}{\scriptstyle\square}
  {\scriptstyle\stretchrel*[74]{\hstretch{#1}{/}}{\square}}{O}{c}{F}{T}{L}}
}{
  \ensurestackMath{\stackengine{0pt}{\scriptscriptstyle\square}
  {\scriptscriptstyle\stretchrel*[66]{\hstretch{#1}{/}}{\square}}{O}{c}{F}{T}{L}}
}}
\begin{document}
$\boxdiag\boxbslash$

$\scriptstyle\boxdiag\boxbslash$

$\scriptscriptstyle\boxdiag\boxbslash$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If your math font changes, the only tweak necessary are on those `\stretchrel*` optional arguments.  For example, with `txfonts` loaded, the option should be `[72]` for all 4 math styles.

[image]

Comment: Neat, although I even don't want to *know* what horror happens if I add those packages :-) (I "solved" the incorrect size when using as subscript by "tiny" before the symbol.)

Comment: @HaukeReddmann Well, `amssymb` is so widely used as to be proofed against all evil.  As to the other two packages, I wrote them, so if horrors happen, come blame me, and I'll see what can be done.

Answer (score 3):

By chance, I noticed that I already have the package `graphicx` loaded (without clashes), which means I can rotate a symbol. Thus the gruesome `\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\mathrlap{\smallsetminus}\square$}` (which of course I meanwhile macro-ed with `\newcommand`) does the trick without any side effects, and looks nearly as perfect as the native box-with-diagonal symbols from the mentioned packages. Case closed :-)
EDIT: Or at least nearly. This hack can't be used inside a `caption` environment (throwing an `incomplete \iffalse` error, as it seems - still experimenting), and when used as index in math mode, utmost care must be taken of brackets and dollars in the right order.

Comment: The problem with `\caption` should vanish if you use `\DeclareRobustCommand` instead of `\newcommand`.